# Dependencies from Android Gradle build - or how to build an Android wear app with Ant these days

Tags: wear-os

Where does Gradle pulls wearable aar files from? I'm specifically looking for compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:*' and compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:*'.  Are there libprojects (exploded aar) for that as well?

I wanted to integrate Android Wear with a legacy ant build. For that to work, I had to create a dummy hello world Wear project on Android Studio, run a gradle script to export the aar dependencies on disk, unzip the aar files and mess around with the directory structure and manually delete some files from the classes.jar archive for it to work as a library project on Android Studio and Ant.

I could not find those libraries in neither the SDK nor Maven public repository.

Google has [some documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually) on how to package your wear app manually, assuming you have the wear apk ready, but is does not mention how to build the wear project without Gradle.

Any points appreciated.

Comment: I'm faced with the same task. Did you manage to solve it? I'm wondering how to embed the wear apk within the mobile apk given that this is usually handled just by adding wear as a dependency in the mobile build.gradle, and how to do a similar thing with ant

Answer (score 0):

Wearable support library is sort of a hidden inside of the docs for Android Wear development. This is the link:

https://developer.android.com/shareables/training/wearable-support-lib.zip